# Ports not connecting, yet I still have Internet access

Tags: ssh, networking, linux-mint, tcp, ufw

I'm currently working on a computer where I'm hosting a website as well as an SSH server. However, when connecting via SSH I receive:

```
ssh: connect to host [ip] port 22: Connection refused
```

In addition, I'm also unable to access my site from any computer/anywhere other than localhost (ssh works from localhost as well), so I suspect it's a port issue. The weird behavior is that I have complete access to the internet with seemingly no problems and so far my processes all seem the be listening on the correct ports.
For example:

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
...
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

As well as lsof, just to be sure:

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN
systemd-r   692 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  28278      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
cupsd       789            root    6u  IPv6  28309      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd       789            root    7u  IPv4  28310      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
mongod      801         mongodb   11u  IPv4  32916      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)
sshd      38855            root    3u  IPv4  89747      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      38855            root    4u  IPv6  89749      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
node      54590            root   21u  IPv6 118616      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

I have firewall rules in place to let traffic through:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

After looking at my router, DHCP is also clearly working and port forwarding rules seem correct, so I feel like I've examined the entire stack. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your router is blocking traffic?

Comment: Some ISPs block inbound traffic, particularly (it seems) in USA

Answer (score 0):

The issue was linked to when I switched to a fresh install of Linux Mint a few weeks ago. When setting up port forwarding, there were multiple entries for my machine under the same name (since I kept my hostname). The one that I was using had old data associated with it and after switching to a different entry all traffic was being forwarded correctly.

I'll leave this post up in case anyone has the same issue and hasn't tried examining devices with the same hostname (even if one is nonexistent/off)